# Wh question structure

Tags: grammar, questions

> What you look like.
>   What do you look like?

When forming the *wh* question, do I need to use a verb or auxiliary verb in between *wh* and subject?

> What · he said · turned out to be true?
>   What ·  did he say · turned out to be true?

> What · you opened it · with?
>   What · did you open it · with?

What do the above sentences mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All full questions* require a finite auxiliary verb<sup>†</sup> (that is, an auxiliary verb tensed for either past or present) *before* the subject. When the verb in the sentence is a construction with an auxiliary, this is accomplished by switching the subject and the auxiliary. When the verb is a lexical verb with no auxiliary, it is accomplished with *DO-support*: the tense is removed from the verb and put on a form of *DO* before the subject:

> He **is** John Smith. → **Is** he John Smith?
>   He **is** [who]. → Who **is** he?
>
> He **has** gone to town. → **Has** he gone to town?
>   He **has** gone [where]. → Where **has** he gone?
>
> You **look** like an executive. → **Do** you **look** like an executive?
>   You **look** like [what]. → What **do** you **look** like?

Your second sentence, however, confuses two different constructions. There *What*  is not an interrogative, a question word, but a *relative pronoun* heading a clause which acts as a noun phrase. The statement form would be:

> [<sub>Subject</sub> What you said] [<sub>Verb</sub> **turned** out] [<sub>Complement</sub> to be true].

Consequently, the question form would be:

> **Did** what you said **turn** out to be true?

---

* As Peter Flom points out, questions may be truncated very substantially in discourse context.
<sup>†</sup> *BE* is always considered an auxiliary, even when it is the only verb.

Comment: As usual, an excellent answer. But what about this construction: "Who? Him?" as in, e.g. if someone says "I think Millard Fillmore is the greatest president of all time!" another person might respond "Who? Him?"

Comment: @PeterFlom Well, there's considerable ellipsis there! 1) ***Who** do you think is the greatest president? Do you really think **him** the greatest president?* (Admittedly, I cheat a little on the case of *HE*; *he*→*him* is really a post-cyclic transform.) I've edited my first sentence.

Comment: @PeterFlom & Stoney: What's wrong with Fillmore? Hm? ;^)

Comment: @J.R. Millard Fillmore's last words were "The nourishment is palatable."

Comment: Why would that disqualify him from greatness? (Sorry, but I can't seem to restrain myself from responding with _wh_ questions – please don't feel the need to answer them.) :^)