# How to form WH question

Tags: grammar

> who is your sister sees ?
>   **who your sister sees  ?**
>
> who are you looking for  ?
>   **who you are looking for ?**

What I know is, All WH questions* require a finite auxiliary verb before the subject,but in this sentence "who your sister likes" ,there is no auxiliary verb.is this sentence in currect format or not.

Comment: Who/Whom does your sister see? And the question with the terminal *is* is okay! But it makes more a sentence than question.

Comment: Recommended readings: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14137/english-grammar-wh-question-forms/14156#14156, http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/9940/3281.

Comment: @MaulikV ,what about "who you are looking for",I found so many results in google.

Comment: 1. The sentence is okay. 2. Don't get allured by the number of Google Results! Also, would you mind putting the question marks in all those sentences? Check Damkerng's links...very useful.

Comment: "who you are looking for" is perfectly OK but is **not** a **direct** question. Direct question "Who are you looking for?". Indirect question: "Tell me who you are looking for." (**no** question mark).

Comment: @Laure, "whom you are trying to reach" or "who you are trying to reach",which one is correct.

Comment: Both are nowadays considered as correct in that case. Look at these two questions and answers [usage of who vs whom](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31510/usage-of-who-vs-whom) and [How can one differentiate between “who” and “whom”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/274/how-can-one-differentiate-between-who-and-whom) and you can ask another question if these don't satisfy you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Direct question**:

> Who does your sister see?

It is a complete sentence with the use of a `WH- word` and an `auxiliary verb`. Question mark at the end.

*who <del>is</del> your sister see<del>s</del>? is not correct English.
You might find [Snaiboat's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/14156/2818), link already provided by  Damkerng T. to understand why.

**Indirect question:**
"who your sister sees" is not a complete sentence, it can be an indirect question subordinate to a main clause. There's no question mark, and the word order is that of a declarative sentence (not a question).

> I'm asking you who your sister sees.
>   I want to know who your sister sees.